# What are the strong arguments against the reassembly of the Ship of Theseus?

Tags: metaphysics, identity

I've been thinking a lot about the Ship of Theseus puzzle, and I find the most convincing solution to be that the ship that comes from the reassembly of the original parts is in fact numerically identical to the original ship. I've been trying to find strong objections for an object to survive the reassembly of its parts, but I'm not sure I've found anything entirely convincing. Could anyone offer an argument that should be examined before accepting the solution, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: The paradox has no solution, it only illustrates the impossibility of having consistent identity over time for changeable objects. Humanity instead goes with pragmatic solutions, like bureaucracy. Theseus own te ship to which he's got the paperwork. In case on ambiguity, a judge decides.

Comment: The main argument against reassembled ship being identical with the original is that it lacks temporal continuity with it, which is often taken as necessary for diachronic identity. Constitution and some relative identity theories then explain the relation between the two as non-identity: it is only constituted by the same parts or is the same collection of parts as the original, but not the same ship. See [SEP, Fission Puzzles](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-time/#4.7).

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.